# How do I clear pins on a mapview in swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, mapkit, android-mapview

Part of my app contains a mapview which searches automatically based on a keyword. I added a textbox and search button to my mapview, but I noticed the pins do not clear from the previous search. How do I clear the map of all pins before the new search?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import iAd

class MapClass: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate {

var searchController:UISearchController!
var annotation:MKAnnotation!
var localSearchRequest:MKLocalSearchRequest!
var localSearch:MKLocalSearch!
var localSearchResponse:MKLocalSearchResponse!
var error:NSError!
var pointAnnotation:MKPointAnnotation!
var pinAnnotationView:MKPinAnnotationView!

var holidayKeyWord = NSString()

@IBOutlet var mapSearchTextbox: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet var adBannerView: ADBannerView!
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

let searchRadius: CLLocationDistance = 2000

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    holidayKeyWord = "Restaurant"

    println(holidayKeyWord)
    mapSearchTextbox.text = holidayKeyWord as String

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    self.adBannerView?.delegate = self
    self.adBannerView?.hidden = false

    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
    {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

}


@IBAction func mapSearchButton(sender: UIButton) {

    //clear pins

    var holidayKeyWord = mapSearchTextbox.text


    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
    {
        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = holidayKeyWord as String
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.startWithCompletionHandler {
            (response: MKLocalSearchResponse!, error: NSError!) in

            for item in response.mapItems as! [MKMapItem] {
                println(item.name)
                self.addPinToMapView(item.name, latitude: item.placemark.location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: item.placemark.location.coordinate.longitude)

            }
        }
    }



}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    //replace spaces with dashes in wikiDate string

    if (segue.identifier == "amazonToWeb") {
        var wikiDate = "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Ddigital-text&field-keywords=\(holidayKeyWord)"
        var DestViewController : WebBrowser = segue.destinationViewController as! WebBrowser
        DestViewController.wikiDate = wikiDate
    }

    if (segue.identifier == "searchToWeb") {
        var wikiDate = "http://www.bing.com"
        var DestViewController : WebBrowser = segue.destinationViewController as! WebBrowser
        DestViewController.wikiDate = wikiDate
    }

    if (segue.identifier == "ebayToWeb") {
        var wikiDate = "http://search.ebay.com/\(holidayKeyWord)"
        var DestViewController : WebBrowser = segue.destinationViewController as! WebBrowser
        DestViewController.wikiDate = wikiDate
    }

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    let location = locations.last as! CLLocation
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    var latitude: Double = location.coordinate.latitude
    var longitude: Double = location.coordinate.longitude
    let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    // 1
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = holidayKeyWord as String
    // 2
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)

    request.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: initialLocation.coordinate, span: span)
    // 3
    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.startWithCompletionHandler {
        (response: MKLocalSearchResponse!, error: NSError!) in


        for item in response.mapItems as! [MKMapItem] {
            println(item.name)
            //println("Latitude = \(item.placemark.location.coordinate.latitude)")
            //println("Longitude = \(item.placemark.location.coordinate.longitude)")
            self.addPinToMapView(item.name, latitude: item.placemark.location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: item.placemark.location.coordinate.longitude)
        }
    }

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(initialLocation.coordinate, searchRadius * 2.0, searchRadius * 2.0)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)

}


func addPinToMapView(title: String, latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) {
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    let annotation = MyAnnotation(coordinate: location, title: title)

    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

}

func removePinFromMapView(title: String, latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) {
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    let annotation = MyAnnotation(coordinate: location, title: title)

    mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)

}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!)
{
    println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Iterate through your annotations and delete them one by one like this:

```
if let annotations = self.mapView.annotations {
    for _annotation in annotations {
        if let annotation = _annotation as? MKAnnotation
        {
            self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks for saving me a ton of time!

Answer (score 11):

There is a short way of doing @ezcoding's answer.

```
mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the pins by saying `addAnnotation`. To remove them, just reverse that: say `removeAnnotation`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3.0

```
func removeAllAnnotations() {
    for annotation in self.mapView.annotations {
        self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```